# What is the shortcut for switching editor panes in CodePen?

Tags: codepen

In Codepen, I have the VIM shortcuts enabled.

But I keep having to use the mouse to switch between the HTML, CSS, and JS panels.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 3):

There's no native keyboard shortcuts for switching between panes in CodePen, but since you asked for it -- and it's a good idea -- here's a Chrome extension that adds that functionality in:

**[codeTabber for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/codetabber/hhlhpibdcfdggipnplpdaboblfblppon?hl=en-US&gl=US)**

Once you install the extension, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> to shift focus to the pane to the left of the current pane, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>></kbd> to shift focus to the pane to the right.  If no pane currently has focus, the HTML pane will get focus.  As of right now, it works anywhere on the screen except when the iframe where the output is shown is the active element, but that's being worked on.

If you don't use Chrome, I'll try to get this up soon for other browsers.  It's free and simple to use.

**UPDATE:** Here's **[codeTabber for Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/codetabber/?display=en)**, and **[codeTabber for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/codetabber/)**.

Comment: I'm getting the following error : 

https://i.imgur.com/pj8ff6p.png 

any idea why ?

Comment: @aeid Weird, the file should be there. Are you using it in Chrome, Firefox, or Opera?

Comment: I am  using chrome .

Comment: I just uninstalled it and reinstalled it in Chrome, works fine. Do you get that error on install? Maybe the download got corrupted.

Comment: This thread isn't the best place to go back and forth troubleshooting it... can you fill out the support form on the [codeTabber web store page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/codetabber/hhlhpibdcfdggipnplpdaboblfblppon/support?hl=en-US&gl=US) or else leave a comment on the [blog page](https://tech-in-check.blogspot.in/p/codetabber-browser-extension.html)?

Comment: This really made being productive easier for me. 1+ upvote from me.